# Exception using dynamics 365 web Api Console

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to create some records on Dynamics 365/CRM using web-api. It works when doing GUID retrieves.

In my scenario I should use the web api from azure via webservices. Wdhen it is invoked it should query entity Lead Sources and set the GUID on entity Lead.

The error occurs when getting the query's result.

This is my code:

```
  using System;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
  using System.Net.Http;
  using System.Net.Http.Headers;
  using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
  using Newtonsoft.Json;

 namespace Integration.Marketing_Activities_Creation
   {
 class Create
 {
    List<string> entityUris = new List<string>();
    string LeadSource1Uri;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Create.RunAsync().Wait();
    }

    public static async Task RunAsync()
    {

        String clientId = "0000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000";
        String redirectUrl = "http://localhost";
        String user = "new@organization.onmicrosoft.com";
        String pass = "********";
        String baseAddress = "https://crm-instance.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/";
        String baseAddressFull = baseAddress + "v8.2/";

        AuthenticationParameters ap = AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync(
                    new Uri(baseAddress)).Result;

        //List<string> entityUris = new List<string>();

        String authorityUrl = ap.Authority;
        String resourceUrl = ap.Resource;

        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl, false);
        UserCredential credentials = new UserCredential(user, pass);
        AuthenticationResult result;
        result = authContext.AcquireToken(resourceUrl, clientId, credentials);
        // = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientId, new Uri(redirectUrl));
        var token = result.AccessToken;

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddressFull);
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

        /*** Create Leads ***/

        string LeadName = "Lead first Name";
        string LeadLastName = "Lead second Name";
        string LeadEmail = "3webapi@lead1.com";
        string LeadTopic = "WebApi Lead 3";
        string LeadSource = "Contact Us";
        HttpResponseMessage response;

        string queryLeadSource;

        queryLeadSource = "new_leadsources?$select=new_leadsourceid,new_name&$filter=new_name eq '" + LeadSource + "'";

        string LSId=null;
        response = await client.GetAsync(queryLeadSource,
            HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            JObject lsRetreived = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(await
                response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            LSId = lsRetreived["new_leadsourceid"].ToString(); /*** outgoing on this line i get an exception and the app crashes :( ***/
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error retrieving tracking Lead Source ID!");
            throw new CrmHttpResponseException(response.Content);
        }

        JObject newLead = new JObject();
        newLead.Add("firstname", LeadName);
        newLead.Add("lastname", LeadLastName);
        newLead.Add("emailaddress1", LeadEmail);
        newLead.Add("subject", LeadTopic);
        newLead.Add("new_leadsource@odata.bind", "/new_leadsources("+ LSId + ")");

        HttpResponseMessage responsePost = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("leads", newLead);

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the Exception you get? And what is the InnerException, if any?

Comment: Hi Martijn, i get this  Message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." string, and then the runconsole explotes :D :( the object it's line 81 when i'm retrieving the GUID on the  LSId = lsRetreived["new_leadsourceid"].ToString();

Comment: Also returns the execption on here  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Create.RunAsync().Wait();
        }

Comment: Your query returns an array of entity objects. Therefore `lsRetreived["new_leadsourceid"]` returns `null` and `.ToString()` throws a `NullReferenceException`. Just set a breakpoint on the line and inspect object `lsRetreived`.

Comment: Hi Henk, no it doesn't return null, it returns the GUID of the LeadSource variable that i send

Comment: So what's your comment "/*** outgoing on this line i get an exception and the app crashes :( ***/" about? What exception do you get? Please add the stack trace to your question.

Comment: Henk when the application is on that line, the exception that i receive is Message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." and stops execution. i mean, on that line i receive the GUID, but the application stops with that message.

Comment: With that little information I doubt we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for be so responsive and helpful Henk, this is the Stact trace   _StackTrace "   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()\r\n   at Integration.Marketing_Activities_Creation.Create.Main(String[] args) in _path_\\Create.cs:line 23" string_

Comment: @Ville: you're missing the stacktrace of the thread that's the source of the exception. Try tracing all exception details or convert your async calls to synchronous ones. Async used this way does not add much benefit anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying `new_leadsources` so you are not getting a single record, you are getting an Array of results. To be more precise, if you call:

```
http://apiurl/new_leadsources?$select=new_leadsourceid,new_name&$filter=new_name eq '" + LeadSource + "'"
```

results will look like this (this is simplified):

```
{
    value: [{
        new_leadsourceid: "guid",
        new_name: "somename"
    }]
}
```

Of course if you have more than one record with the same name, you will get more records in this Array, but it's still an Array.

So in this line:

```
LSId = lsRetreived["new_leadsourceid"].ToString();
```

you are trying to access "new_leadsourceid" property of object which has only "value" property.
Having in mind the structure of the response you should do something like this:

```
LSId = lsRetreived["value"][0]["new_leadsourceid"].ToString();
```

Of course this code is awful and error prone (it assumes that there is always at leas one result and always takes the first result), but it should get you going in the right direction.

Also - use the debugger, it really helps to get the idea what's going on with your code, based on your comments I assume you did not take any time on debugging.

Comment: Hi Pawel, thanks for your feedback, i'm using the debugger but i'm not Deep on .NET developing, so have stuffs that i'm carrying to understand, but, on your example, you mean i have to set the value that i need?
i mean, doing this `http://apiurl/new_leadsources?$select=new_leadsourceid&$filter=new_name eq '" + LeadSource ` im querying just one value so the array should retrieve just ONE result, and that parameter i should use it on

`LSId = lsRetreived["parameter_needed_example"][0]["new_leadsource"].ToString();`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Again - look how the response from the service looks like (the JSON structure). "Value" is not a parameter, it's just there as field in this JSON object. So I don't understand what is "parameter_needed_example", there should be "value" as simple as that. Have you even tried the code that I posted? I provided for you the whole line, just copy paste it and replace your current line...

Comment: Thanks Pawel! i was with other stuffs, but today i copy and paste your line and works like a charm :D... just to clarify "parameter_needed_example" you're right, seting "value" works, setting the name of the entity doesn't, and that's my fault :D